# Paraview in jupyter notebook for OpenFoam: No module named vtkCommonCorePython

Tags: python, paraview, openfoam

I am trying to use paraview to write a script which automates the generation of a paticular vizualization of an OpenFoam solution. I am using Jupyter Notebook. 
I didnt build paraview seperately. It came with "OpenFoam-in-a-box". 
I also have 2 versions of Python on my machine 2.7 and 3.5.

Given the situation I set up two path variables as following:

```
import sys
username = getpass.getuser()

sys.path.append('/home/'+username+'/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-in-Box/OpenFOAM- 
in-Box-18.02/ThirdParty-dev/platforms/linux64Gcc62/ParaView- 
5.4.1/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/')
import paraview

sys.path.append('/home/'+username+'/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages')
from paraview.simple import *
```

This throws an error like this :

```
Error: Could not import vtkCommonComputationalGeometry
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-35ff85eed6df> in <module>()
      4 import paraview
      5 sys.path.append('/home/'+username+'/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
----> 6 from paraview.simple import *

/home/username/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-in-Box/OpenFOAM-in-Box-18.02/ThirdParty-dev/platforms/linux64Gcc62/ParaView-5.4.1/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/paraview/simple.py in <module>()
     41 
     42 import paraview
---> 43 from paraview import servermanager
     44 import paraview._backwardscompatibilityhelper
     45 

    /home/username/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-in-Box/OpenFOAM-in-Box-18.02/ThirdParty-dev/platforms/linux64Gcc62/ParaView-5.4.1/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/paraview/servermanager.py in <module>()
         51 # prefer `vtk` from `paraview` since it doesn't import all
         52 # vtk modules.
    ---> 53 from paraview import vtk
         54 from paraview import _backwardscompatibilityhelper as _bc
         55 

    /home/username/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-in-Box/OpenFOAM-in-Box-18.02/ThirdParty-dev/platforms/linux64Gcc62/ParaView-5.4.1/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/paraview/vtk/__init__.py in <module>()
          5 except ImportError:
          6     paraview.print_error("Error: Could not import vtkCommonComputationalGeometry")
    ----> 7 from paraview.vtk.vtkCommonCore import *
          8 from paraview.vtk.vtkCommonDataModel import *
          9 from paraview.vtk.vtkCommonExecutionModel import *

    /home/username/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-in-Box/OpenFOAM-in-Box-18.02/ThirdParty-dev/platforms/linux64Gcc62/ParaView-5.4.1/lib/paraview-5.4/site-packages/paraview/vtk/vtkCommonCore.py in <module>()
          7     # during build and testing, the modules will be elsewhere,
          8     # e.g. in lib directory or Release/Debug config directories
    ----> 9     from vtkCommonCorePython import *

    ImportError: No module named vtkCommonCorePython
```

I have pretty much spend the whole day reasearching about this but just can't fix this. Any help would be appreciated !!

Comment: I had the same issue I solved the problem [here](https://discourse.paraview.org/t/not-able-to-import-paraview-simple-module-on-windows/537/9?u=foadsf).

Answer (score 0):

Installing paraview using conda fixed it. You dont even need to set up path variables.

```
conda install -c conda-forge paraview
```